# design sprit icons for big site

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-sprites

what is the best for design full icons and images sprite for big site.. **before** UI Development or **after** ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the design process, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this is [programming-related](https://stackoverflow.com/faq/) for one second, however I'd suggest that the best time for designing the icons and images for a site would be the same time at which the UI is being designed, since the icons/images have to fit the general aesthetic of the site itself.

Obviously this is only the *initial* design (and don't be afraid to amend, revise, re-design later) but it seems a mistake to think of icons and UI separately as distinct entities, rather than...symbiotic, maybe?

Comment: thank you.. but i think create sprite is hard work i don't need problem.. see this sprite is very complex http://s11.cc/ge9e

Comment: @Anas AbuDayah, I'm sorry? Did someone promise you web-design was going to be *easy*? You don't have to do the whole thing at once, just figure out which elements you need to start with, to help you visualise the aesthetic of the site, and then work from there to refine and expand the design.

Comment: thank you.. that is for css optimization only.. i will create simple sprite in the first